# Parse JSON elements of a list returned from a multi-choice column in Power Automate/MS flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, power-automate, multiple-values

I am calling the SP API to get the version history of an item in my list as follows:

```
 _api/web/lists/getbytitle('@{triggerBody()?['SPListName']}')/items(@{triggerBody()?['SPListID']})/versions?$top=20
```

I am getting the values and parse them with a JSON parser as explained [here](https://d365demystified.com/2020/04/12/using-parse-json-to-read-individual-list-records-in-flowpower-automate/),

I can get all the values of the columns of my list without any issue, however I have a multi-choice column which returns the below string as the result of the Parse JSON action

```
 {"__metadata":{"type":"Collection(Edm.String)"},"results":["Choice 2"]}
```

if I select two choices in my multi-choice column, I get the below result:

```
{"__metadata":{"type":"Collection(Edm.String)"},"results":["Choice 1","Choice 3"]}
```

How can I only get the value in the "results" section as a string such as "Choice 1","Choice 3" rather than the whole metadata string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating for **[Send a HTTP..]** request. Here [results] is an array, and [MyChoice] is also an array.

```
body('Parse_JSON')?['d']?['results'][1]['MyChoice'][0]['Value']
```

---

Here's how I can find individual choice value when retrieving list items using [Get items] -> [Parse JSON] -> [Apply to each]

Here for each item, [MyChoice] is the Property (column name of the multi-value), and [0] is the index of the first value. You can check the length of [MyChoice] and dynamically find each value.

```
items('Apply_to_each')['MyChoice'][0]['Value']
```

[image]

---

### Updating the answer showing how to dynamically capture values from a multi-value column

Please see the screenshots and explanation below.

Please note that it's very important to analyze the output from [Send an HTTP..] by using a [Compose] action before feeding into [Parse JSON]

[image]

**Detail Apply to each 2**
[image]

**Detail - Loop for Choices per item (inner loop)**
[image]

**Detail 3**
[image]

Comment: Thank you, How can I check the length of MyChoice dynamically?, can you show me a code or screenshot to iterate through MyChoice and get each value and append it to an array based on the output of Parse JSON?

Comment: I am doing it by if(greater(indexof(string(items('Apply_to_each_History_Parse_JSON')?['BudgetSource']),'['),1),replace(replace(replace(string(items('Apply_to_each_History_Parse_JSON')?['BudgetSource']),'{"__metadata":{"type":"Collection(Edm.String)"},"results":[',''),']}',''),'"',''),''), but any better solution?

Comment: I'm almost done posting the update.. give me a few minutes

Comment: Sure thanks a lot, no rush

Comment: Update completed. Note that there are two loops, one at the item level and within that the loop for choices of each item. Since you know the **length** of the [MyChoices][results], you can use **[Do Until]** loop as well. It depends how you want to use it. But let me know if you have any further questions

Comment: Thank you Matiur, I have not tried it, but you explained it very well and make sense, I am sure it gonna work, all the steps are logical. thanks a lot for the time and effort you put into this. Much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome. Let me know if you still see any issues

Comment: Sure, will be in touch, thanks again and have a great time. Hope it gets lots of up votes:)