# Getting the value from a lookup column in Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, lookup-column, power-automate

Pretty simple: I have a lookup column that references another list of strings (multiple selection text field). In a workflow I want to get the values from that lookup column so I can put them in an email.

The email goes something like this:

> Hello [user], [person] has requested you take the following actions: [actions]

The [actions] part is simply putting in that lookup column, I want to list all the actions that have been selected. I'm getting halfway there, it does return the list of actions, but it comes back with a lot of unnecessary data in addition to the values. Here's what it looks like now:

```
[{"@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference","Id":1,"Value":"Approval"},{"@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference","Id":4,"Value":"Coordinate"},{"@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference","Id":9,"Value":"Note and return"}].
```

Question: How do I simply select the values from a lookup column in Power Automate?

Comment: I've already posted a response in this forum, you can take a look [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/286095/parse-json-elements-of-a-list-returned-from-a-multi-choice-column-in-power-autom/286108#286108)

Answer (score 0):

Please try as follows:

[image]

Then use the following expression in email body:

```
substring(variables('All action value'),0,sub(length(variables('All action value')),1))
```

[image]

My test list:

[image]

Email I received:

[image]

Similar issue for your reference:

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/SharePoint-lookup-column-with-multi-value-to-email/td-p/101158